# Jira/Confluence hogging memory with lots of processes

Tags: process, debian-squeeze, memory-usage, jira, confluence

We've been working with Jira and Confluence on a Debian 6 VPS for a while now. Everything is fine as far as their daily use is concerned.

The issue we are encountering now is that occasionally, the VPS hosting both solutions will hang on CPU overcharge or even crash after a huge memory usage.

This was not happening before adding Confluence to Jira.

I have noticed lots and lots of unterminated logging processes from both of them, and I was wondering if that was a normal situation or if something was wrong with our setup.

Here is a screenshot of the `htop` showing that huge list of processes:

[image]

The same goes on for Confluence.

My question is the following : is it a normal situation? Are these still alive and possibly causing a memory hog later on?

I haven't been able to find any clues regarding that matter yet.

Any suggestions?

Comment: No, this is not normal. What did Atlassian support say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not logging processes. The lines you can see in htop are Java threads. Each thread is showing the command line arguments of the Java process that was used to start JIRA.

If you are are concerned about the number of threads running, you can get a thread dump of the process and review the them and what they are doing. The easiest way to do this is issue a

```
kill -3 <pid>
```

This will cause a thread dump to be printed to catalina.out. You will want to collect thread dumps over time to make comparisons. There are also tools like tda that can read these thread dumps and put them into a more readable format.

Your problem you have described is unlikely to be the number of threads running, IMO.

Comment: Forgot to update this topic. Got an actual answer from Atlassian Support stating that I was indeed mistaken and was looking at threads and not processes. In the end, the situation is normal and I was probably just overzealous on this matter. Thank you all for your inputs on this. Just in case someone needs to view threads or processes in `htop`, simply press `shift`+`H` to switch between both views.